# JOLT add object name into body as new property

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON payload and I would like to add the software architecture designation (x86 or x64) as a new property called architecture.

```json
{
  "name": "T15P-GEN3",
  "software": {
    "x86": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "version": "1.3.4",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{3A969900-CAD5-4FB8-B5D1-1F8D9028C6AA}"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBB",
        "version": "1.1.2",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{102C3B71-22B5-4484-8D1F-1C859CA6EE63}"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "version": "1.1.4",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{D65355E4-021A-4B0C-B9A4-9D90F8C0D106}"
      }
    ],
    "x64": [
      {
        "name": "AAAA (x64)",
        "version": "24.01",
        "uninstall": "'C:\\Program Files\\AAAA\\Uninstall.exe'"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBBB (2023)",
        "version": "5.5.5.2811",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{92EC01FE-5C8D-4D03-B8D1-F0A2AEF14EB3}"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCCC",
        "version": "",
        "uninstall": "C:\\Program Files\\CCCC\\CCCC_x64.exe -?uninstall"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired output would be:

```json
{
  "name": "T15P-GEN3",
  "software": {
    "x86": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "version": "1.3.4",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{3A969900-CAD5-4FB8-B5D1-1F8D9028C6AA}",
        "architecture": "x86"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBB",
        "version": "1.1.2",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{102C3B71-22B5-4484-8D1F-1C859CA6EE63}",
        "architecture": "x86"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "version": "1.1.4",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{D65355E4-021A-4B0C-B9A4-9D90F8C0D106}",
        "architecture": "x86"
      }
    ],
    "x64": [
      {
        "name": "AAAA (x64)",
        "version": "24.01",
        "uninstall": "'C:\\Program Files\\AAAA\\Uninstall.exe'",
        "architecture": "x64"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBBB (2023)",
        "version": "5.5.5.2811",
        "uninstall": "MsiExec.exe /I{92EC01FE-5C8D-4D03-B8D1-F0A2AEF14EB3}",
        "architecture": "x64"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCCC",
        "version": "",
        "uninstall": "C:\\Program Files\\CCCC\\CCCC_x64.exe -?uninstall",
        "architecture": "x64"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried experimenting based on the following posts [JOLT add object name into body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70940611/jolt-add-object-name-into-body) and [JOLT add property based on name of another property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586121/jolt-add-property-based-on-name-of-another-property) but cannot get it to work the way I want it.

```json
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "software": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&3[].&",
          "$": "&3[].&.architecture"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have just started working with Jolt transformations, but this one is a bit too difficult for me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*":"&", // the elements other than the software object
      "software": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3.&2[&1]",
            "$1": "&3.&2[&1].architecture"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **$** copies from one upper level while **$1** from two upper
- **&1** within **[&1]** loops the indexes of the indexes of the arrays(eg. x86 and x64)
- **&3** and **&2** represent the keys **software** and **x86**, **x64** respectively

Comment: Thanks a lot also for the explanation. This way I may learn how to do proper navigation in the input myself.